# Input send NULL array on laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, input, controller

i have this error when I try to send an array to my database table. i have this on my update method

```
$post = Post::findOrFail($id);
$post->PostTitle = $request->PostTitle;
$post->post = $request->post;

$tags = new Tag;

foreach ($request->tags as $tags) {

    $tag = Tag::create(['tag' => $tags]);

    if ($tag->save()) {
        $post->tags()->sync($tag->id);
    }
}
```

this is my html form

```
<div class="post-panel-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="postTags">Etiquetas: </label>
            <input type="text" name="tags[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Etiquetas" value="<?php if(isset($post->tags)){ foreach($post->tags as $tag); echo $tag->tag;} ?>" id="tagBox2">
```

I have ManyToMany relationship model, all run fine in create method but no on update. I think i miss something but not finded yet.

Comment: Your input name in your form is `taggged`, not `tags`. And the field is most likely malformed from the way you're creating it in your form.

Comment: I edit the input name, jut a typo. i dont understand what you said. i was try to changed variable name, but it doesn't work.

Comment: If you look at the source code of the form in the browser, you'll see your value is `12342236` if your post has the tags 1, 2, 3, 4, 22, and 36. You should probably put the tags field inside the foreach instead.

Comment: Also, you are using `sync` which means each time through the loop, you are going to erase all past tags you just saved for that post.  You probably want to use `attach` instead.

Comment: Also if i use attach, the input is send a null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sync()` method takes an array as parameter. You are passing an object.

Create an array of IDs first, then pass it to the sync function.

```
$ids = [];
foreach ($request->tags as $tags) {
    $tag = Tag::create(['tag'=>$tags]);
    $ids[] = $tag->id;
}

//sync 
$post->tags()->sync($ids); //array of ids
```

Comment: I thought that my mistake was to pass an object instead of an array, but i saw that my input don't send any value to my controller, i try with all method, post, put, but nothing i don't get it.

Comment: View the source code of your form. Do you see any value in the input?

Comment: <input type="text" name="tags[]" class="form-control" value="etqiueta 1" placeholder="Etiquetas" id="tagBox2" tabindex="-1" style="position: absolute; left: -10000px;">

Comment: I will order my idea again, i want to attach new tags on post if people write on it, if not just leave the tags same as the post was created.

Comment: so `request->tags` should return 'etqiueta 1'. In your controller do `dd($request->tags);` and see what it displays.

Comment: `Tag {#214 ▼
  +timestamps: false
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "id"
  ]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  #attributes: array:1 [▼
    "tag" => null
  ]
  #original: []
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #fillable: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}`

Comment: `"tag" => null` means your tag value is empty somehow. You  need to figure that out. Also `$request->tags` should return 'etqiueta 1' which is the value. But instead, it's returning you a full `Tag` object. Please, do `dd($request->tags);` first line in the function. Before the loop. Before anything else.

Comment: `dd($request->tags)` give me `null`

Comment: Try with the global helper. `dd( request('tags') );`

Comment: Same null value, if i do on create method, return me this `Post {#195 ▼
  #filliable: array:3 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:8 [▶]
  #original: array:8 [▶]
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: true
}
"tag1, tag2"`

Comment: i find the error, is the javascript plugin that i use for styling tags, i think what is passing the value as a object and not an array.